# Group items in Views by value in Field Collection

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type (content type X) containing a Field Collection field. 
This Field Collection field consists of a Node Reference (content type Y) field and a text field.

I would like to create a view where I group items based on the nodes selected in the field collection field.

An example:

**Node 1:**

Field collection:

- Node ABC : text here
- Node BCA : text here

**Node 2:**

Field collection:

- Node BCA : text here
- Node CDE : text here

---

The view showing these items would look like the following:

**ABC**

- Node 1

**BCA**

- Node 1
- Node 2

**CDE**

- Node 2

---

How would I be able to create a view like this?
I'm sure I need to use relations, but honestly I have no idea where to start.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Have you try the "Grouping field Nr.1" in "Format" Settings?

Answer (score 2):

*Very nice question!*

I give you every detail step by step, including the structure of content types.

First install [Field Collection Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) module. This will add a default View in Views menu. Its name is `field_collection_view`. Clone this view (recommended) or edit the existing one.

## Content Type X

This is the *Manage Fields* of this content type

[image]

It contains a `Title` and a Field Collection field that I called `xxx`. This is the `xxx`

[image]

It only contains an Entity reference to `y`, I called it `field_reference_xxx` (you can also include other fields, for our purpose it is unnecessary).

## Content Type y

It only has `Title` field and nothing else.

I inserted the exact content you included in the question.

Node1 (`x`) to `abd` and `bca`

Node2 (`x`) to `bca` and `cde`

## field_collection_view View

This is the main work to do. The default View of field collection is in `/admin/structure/views/view/field_collection_view` path. Open it.

First you need to add two *Relationships* :

> **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity**
>
> A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via field_reference_xxx

*Make sure to select **referenced**  not **referencing***

and the second one:

> **Field collection item: Entity with the xxx (field_field_collection)**
>
> Relate each Content using xxx.

I supposed the *Contextual Filter* for selecting is *Title* of content type `y`, right? so let's do it. add Title as contextual filter and make it to use `(Content entity referenced from field_reference_xxx) Content: Title` relationships.

So far so good. Now go to **Fields** section. select `Title` as a field and make it to use **(field_field_collection)** relationships. I mean this

[image]

**AND NOW OUR WORK IS DONE!**

In the aggregate This should be your configuration

[image]

For testing I give you the following screenshots to make sure it works

**Without any value**

[image]

**With bca**

[image]

**With abc**

[image]

**and cde**

[image]

Good Luck!